# Is there a workaround to install WSO2 ESB Amazon S3 Connector?

Tags: wso2-esb

When I try to [install](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Using+a+Connector) the [WSO2 ESB Amazon S3 Connector](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Amazon+S3+Connector) in WSO2 Developer Studio I get the error message

```
Connector directory name amazons3-1.0.0 doesn't match with the connector name amazons3-connector-1.0.0 valid connector should have 'name-connector-1.0.0' format
```

I tried to install both by downloading the zip and selecting the amazones3 connector directly from the WSO2 Shop from inside devstudio.

I am able to install other connectors and the downloaded zip seems to be valid.

Installing the connector same zip through the ESB Management Console works as expected.

I am using the latest DevStudio (3.8.0) and WSO2 ESB 4.8.1

**Edited**:
Yes I have already tried renaming the zip to amazons3-connector-1.0.0.zip. This does not help but only makes the error message even more confusing since it now states amazons3-connector-1.0.0 twice. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

extract the connector and open connector.xml file. make sure it is as follows

(If developer studio version less than 3.8)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<connector>
    <component name="amazons3-connector-1.0.0" package="org.wso2.carbon.connector" >
        <dependency component="amazon_buckets"/>
        <dependency component="amazon_config"/>
        <dependency component="amazon_objects"/>
        <description>amazon S3 connector libraries</description>
    </component>
</connector>
```

(If developer studio version 3.8)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<connector>
    <component name="amazons3" package="org.wso2.carbon.connector" >
        <dependency component="amazon_buckets"/>
        <dependency component="amazon_config"/>
        <dependency component="amazon_objects"/>
        <description>amazon S3 connector libraries</description>
    </component>
</connector>
```

Name of the zip file does not matters.

Note: i think this is bug on either side. may be new version on dev studio or connector which is in store. i will check this and update here later.

Thanks @Pontus for your input

***update :
This issue has been fixed on connector. now amazonS3 connector can use without above modification***

Comment: Yes the connector.xml has the content you've pasted above. However comparing this connector.xml with a connector.xml from a working connector zip shows that the name should perhaps just be "amazons3"

Comment: The following solution worked. Unpack, edit the context.xml to have name="amazons3" and then re-package the files into a new zip that is named amazons3-connector-1.0.0.zip. If you update your answer to include these steps I would be happy to accept.

Comment: Thanks. I just tested the latest version from the store and while that version loads in DevStudio I am unable to deploy it in ESB 4.8.1 due to failed dependencies. I will open up a new question on this. Also it seems odd that the version in Store is still 1.0.0 even though the actual artifact has changed.